# I want to get the lowest price in steammarket

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, parsing, steam-web-api

[enter image description here][1] I wrote this awful parser to get permanent selling price.

I run it in normal mode in Pycharm but it print "None".
But in Debug mode it returns permanent selling price .

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

def permanent_sale_price(name: str):
    url = "".join(("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/", name))
    PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedgedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    items = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "market_commodity_buyrequests")
    tx = item.text.split(" ")
    price = float(tx[-1][1:])
    return price

def main():
    name = "P250 | Franklin (Field-Tested)"
    print(permanent_sale_price(name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

"[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Est2D.png permanent selling price ,id in html "market_commodity_buyrequests" "

(P. S. without Loop)

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: My quistion is Why it returns None when I run it , but When I debug this code (stop point in 13 line) it returns number which i need

Comment: why you use a for loop and return together ? maybe you should use yield instead or change the code.

Comment: _But it works normal in Debug mode_: What happens in automated mode? Which is the **permanent selling price** the one you want to extract?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes (1) a question :-) and (2) the details of the debugging session which you refer to.  As it stands, it does not contain enough information to provide an answer. Please do not use comments (nor the title) to add details to your question; the question itself should be self-contained.

Comment: if it returns none is most probably because the loop does not iterate, which means that items is empty. Or the first element of items is None (you only return the first one in your loop, which is most likely a bug)

Comment: item = driver.find_element(By.ID, "market_commodity_buyrequests")
    tx = item.text.split(" ")
    price = float(tx[-1][1:])
    return price

Comment: maybe because as @SembeiNorimaki said, the list returned by find_elements() is empty, due to the code which is faster than selenium to load the page (do you get error when run this code ?) and this is why when you use debug it works. Try to use time.sleep() or WebDriverWait()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def permanent_sale_price(name: str):
    url = "".join(("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/", name))
    PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedgedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,  "market_commodity_buyrequests"))
    )
    items = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "market_commodity_buyrequests")
    tx = item.text.split(" ")
    price = float(tx[-1][1:])
    return price

def main():
    name = "P250 | Franklin (Field-Tested)"
    print(permanent_sale_price(name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```